# using lambdas or QSignalMapping to pass a custom class value into custom SLOT

Tags: qt, lambda, qt5

I am using Qt5.

I have a loop which generates multiple (number specified by the user) plots by using QCustomPlot (http://www.qcustomplot.com/) each shown in their own dialog. I want the user to be able to save one of the plots, so in each dialog there is a menu bar with an Action "Save as PDF".

I have a List of the plots (QList< QCustomPlot*> >) which each plot is added to when it is created in the loop. My issue is how to select from the list which plot should be saved when the user triggers the action. Here's the main code:

```
while(currentPlotNum<NumPlots){

//code for generating plots

QAction *saveAsPdfAction = new QAction("Save As PDF",plotDialog); 
QFileDialog *saveAsPdfDialog = new QFileDialog(plotDialog);
saveAsPdfDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
saveAsPdfDialog->setNameFilter("PDF Files (*.pdf)");

QObject::connect(saveAsPdfAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),saveAsPdfDialog,SLOT(exec()));
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(saveAsPdfDialog);
QObject::connect(saveAsPdfAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),signalMapper,SLOT(map()));
signalMapper->setMapping(saveAsPdfAction,currentPlotNum);
QObject::connect(signalMapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SLOT(setWorkingPlot(int)));
QObject::connect(saveAsPdfDialog,SIGNAL(fileSelected(QString)),this,SLOT(saveToPDF(QString)));

currentPlotNum++;
}
```

then here are the two SLOTS:

```
void samplePlots::setWorkingPlot(int value){
    workingPlot = value;
}
void samplePlots::saveToPDF(QString PdfFileName){
    plotList[workingPlot]->savePdf(PdfFileName,false,600,600);
}
```

I run the application and generate say 3 plots, when I click the button to save one of the plots, the plot that actually gets saved is seemingly a random choice of one of the 3, rather than the plot in the dialog which i click the button in.

Ideally I would have been able to pass the QCustomPlot* itself through the SignalMaper, but it doesn't seem as though I can do that. I also tried to have the Slot as a lambda (following the syntax here http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/09/qt-5-and-c11-lambdas-are-your-friend/ but I couldn't get it to work.

If anyone has Ideas of how to fix my problem that would be great.

Comment: It seems a little unnecessary to create a new `QFileDialog` for every `saveAsPdfAction`. *Ideally I would have been able to pass the QCustomPlot itself through the SignalMaper, but it doesn't seem as though I can do that* Why not? Did you look into [`QSignalMapper::setMapping(QObject *sender, QWidget *widget)`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html#setMapping-3) function? I think you should use signal mapper for your `saveAsPdfAction`'s `triggered` signal, and then connect the `mapped(QWidget *widget)` signal of the signal mapper to a slot which will show the file dialog.

Comment: Also you only need one `QSignalMapper` object.

Comment: ..or you can use the `mapped(int)` signal like you already are doing, but instead of having a slot for setting the `workingPlot` variable that you use in the `saveToPDF` slot, use just one slot that takes an `int` as an argument and open a file dialog to choose a file in that slot. Then connect this slot to the `mapped(int)` signal.

Answer (score 1):

Connect each 'saveToPdf buttons' `triggered(bool)` signal to a custom signal of your derived displaying `QDialog` (lets call it `saveRequested()`).
store in the dialog the index of the displaying plot as well and save your `QSignalMapper` (not needed).

then connect your main class where your list is stored to that `saveRequested()` signal, cast the `QObject::sender()` to your Dialog and access the plot in the list.

cheers